# Angular 6 - Dynamic page with Angular materials

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to build a dynamic HTML page based on JSON data.

For Ex :- I am expecting the page with 20% box on left & 80% box on right and then the right box separated as top with 60% and bottom with 40%

I am not sure, how to achieve this with angular material & css.

```
{
   "horizontal" : [
     {
      width : 20%,
      height: 100%
     },
     {
       "vertical" : [
         {
           width : 80%,
           height: 60%
         },
         {
           width : 80%,
           height: 40%
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean, is this a layout? header footer sidebar?

Comment: This is a layout based on JSON data. But, may not be header and footer. Header and footer may be constant. Just the work area.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use JSON and angular material to create a dynamic page layout, but you need to adjust your JSON structure a bit.

> I am expecting the page with 20% box on left & 80% box on right and
>   then the right box separated as top with 60% and bottom with 40%

The structure you're describing is a container with two columns. The first column has no additional content whereas the second column contains two rows. This can be represented like this:

```
layout = [
    {
      /* container */
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      columns: [
        /* first column */
        {
          width: "20%",
          height: "100%",    
        },
        /* second column */
        {
          width: "80%",
          height: "100%",
          rows: [
            {
              /* first row of second column */
              width: "100%",
              height: "60%",
            },
            {
              /* second row of second column */
              width: "100%",
              height: "40%",    
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

To make the layout visible you have to loop over all the columns and rows in your template file and set the appropriate @angular/flex-layout attributes:

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="column">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let container of style">
        <div fxFlex="0 0 {{container.width}}" [ngStyle]="{ 'height': container.height }" class="row">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of container.columns">
                <div fxFlex="{{col.width}}" [ngStyle]="{ 'height': col.height }" class="col" fxLayout="row wrap">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of col.rows">
                        <div fxFlex="{{row.width}}" [ngStyle]="{ 'height': row.height }" class="row">
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-page-with-angular-materials) for you so you can check the complete code and test it by changing the values for the container, columns and rows.

This code only works with your provided depths of nesting (container > columns > rows). If you need more or an unknown number of levels in your layout, you could make this layout even more generic if you work with `ng-template` e.g. like in this [generic layout stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-page-with-angular-materials-fully-generic).